# How to add filter effects to camera preview for choosing a filter before taking picture?

Tags: android, camera, android-gpuimageview

I am developing a camera application using camera api for below lollipop version and camera 2 for lolipop and above versions ,My problem is, I don't know how to add filter effects to the camera preview (like, candycam and retrica camera apps) to add a filter effect before taking a picture.I have seen many camera applications in playstore have the facility to choose filter effect before clicking for a snap.And I have used GPU Image filter to add filters to an image in imageview ,i hope the same can be used for the camera preview.But i don't know how to do that?can anyone help?

I have used this class to add Filter effects to an image

```
public class GPUImageFilterTools {  
public static void showDialog(final Context context,
        final OnGpuImageFilterChosenListener listener) {
    final FilterList filters = new FilterList();
    filters.addFilter("Contrast", FilterType.CONTRAST);
    filters.addFilter("Invert", FilterType.INVERT);
    filters.addFilter("Pixelation", FilterType.PIXELATION);
    filters.addFilter("Hue", FilterType.HUE);
    filters.addFilter("Gamma", FilterType.GAMMA);
    filters.addFilter("Brightness", FilterType.BRIGHTNESS);
    filters.addFilter("Sepia", FilterType.SEPIA);
    filters.addFilter("Grayscale", FilterType.GRAYSCALE);
    filters.addFilter("Sharpness", FilterType.SHARPEN);
    filters.addFilter("Sobel Edge Detection", FilterType.SOBEL_EDGE_DETECTION);
    filters.addFilter("3x3 Convolution", FilterType.THREE_X_THREE_CONVOLUTION);
    filters.addFilter("Emboss", FilterType.EMBOSS);
    filters.addFilter("Posterize", FilterType.POSTERIZE);
    filters.addFilter("Grouped filters", FilterType.FILTER_GROUP);
    filters.addFilter("Saturation", FilterType.SATURATION);
    filters.addFilter("Exposure", FilterType.EXPOSURE);
    filters.addFilter("Highlight Shadow", FilterType.HIGHLIGHT_SHADOW);
    filters.addFilter("Monochrome", FilterType.MONOCHROME);
    filters.addFilter("Opacity", FilterType.OPACITY);
    filters.addFilter("RGB", FilterType.RGB);
    filters.addFilter("White Balance", FilterType.WHITE_BALANCE);
    filters.addFilter("Vignette", FilterType.VIGNETTE);
    filters.addFilter("ToneCurve", FilterType.TONE_CURVE);

    filters.addFilter("Blend (Difference)", FilterType.BLEND_DIFFERENCE);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Source Over)", FilterType.BLEND_SOURCE_OVER);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Color Burn)", FilterType.BLEND_COLOR_BURN);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Color Dodge)", FilterType.BLEND_COLOR_DODGE);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Darken)", FilterType.BLEND_DARKEN);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Dissolve)", FilterType.BLEND_DISSOLVE);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Exclusion)", FilterType.BLEND_EXCLUSION);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Hard Light)", FilterType.BLEND_HARD_LIGHT);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Lighten)", FilterType.BLEND_LIGHTEN);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Add)", FilterType.BLEND_ADD);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Divide)", FilterType.BLEND_DIVIDE);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Multiply)", FilterType.BLEND_MULTIPLY);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Overlay)", FilterType.BLEND_OVERLAY);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Screen)", FilterType.BLEND_SCREEN);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Alpha)", FilterType.BLEND_ALPHA);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Color)", FilterType.BLEND_COLOR);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Hue)", FilterType.BLEND_HUE);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Saturation)", FilterType.BLEND_SATURATION);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Luminosity)", FilterType.BLEND_LUMINOSITY);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Linear Burn)", FilterType.BLEND_LINEAR_BURN);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Soft Light)", FilterType.BLEND_SOFT_LIGHT);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Subtract)", FilterType.BLEND_SUBTRACT);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Chroma Key)", FilterType.BLEND_CHROMA_KEY);
    filters.addFilter("Blend (Normal)", FilterType.BLEND_NORMAL);

    filters.addFilter("Lookup (Amatorka)", FilterType.LOOKUP_AMATORKA);
    filters.addFilter("Gaussian Blur", FilterType.GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
    filters.addFilter("Crosshatch", FilterType.CROSSHATCH);

    filters.addFilter("Box Blur", FilterType.BOX_BLUR);
    filters.addFilter("CGA Color Space", FilterType.CGA_COLORSPACE);
    filters.addFilter("Dilation", FilterType.DILATION);
    filters.addFilter("Kuwahara", FilterType.KUWAHARA);
    filters.addFilter("RGB Dilation", FilterType.RGB_DILATION);
    filters.addFilter("Sketch", FilterType.SKETCH);
    filters.addFilter("Toon", FilterType.TOON);
    filters.addFilter("Smooth Toon", FilterType.SMOOTH_TOON);

    filters.addFilter("Bulge Distortion", FilterType.BULGE_DISTORTION);
    filters.addFilter("Glass Sphere", FilterType.GLASS_SPHERE);
    filters.addFilter("Haze", FilterType.HAZE);
    filters.addFilter("Laplacian", FilterType.LAPLACIAN);
    filters.addFilter("Non Maximum Suppression", FilterType.NON_MAXIMUM_SUPPRESSION);
    filters.addFilter("Sphere Refraction", FilterType.SPHERE_REFRACTION);
    filters.addFilter("Swirl", FilterType.SWIRL);
    filters.addFilter("Weak Pixel Inclusion", FilterType.WEAK_PIXEL_INCLUSION);
    filters.addFilter("False Color", FilterType.FALSE_COLOR);

    filters.addFilter("Color Balance", FilterType.COLOR_BALANCE);

    filters.addFilter("Levels Min (Mid Adjust)", FilterType.LEVELS_FILTER_MIN);

    filters. addFilter("Bilateral Blur", FilterType.BILATERAL_BLUR);


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Choose a filter");
    builder.setItems(filters.names.toArray(new String[filters.names.size()]),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int item) {
                    listener.onGpuImageFilterChosenListener(
                            createFilterForType(context, filters.filters.get(item)));
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
}

private static GPUImageFilter createFilterForType(final Context context, final FilterType type) {
    switch (type) {
        case CONTRAST:
            return new GPUImageContrastFilter(2.0f);
        case GAMMA:
            return new GPUImageGammaFilter(2.0f);
        case INVERT:
            return new GPUImageColorInvertFilter();
        case PIXELATION:
            return new GPUImagePixelationFilter();
        case HUE:
            return new GPUImageHueFilter(90.0f);
        case BRIGHTNESS:
            return new GPUImageBrightnessFilter(1.5f);
        case GRAYSCALE:
            return new GPUImageGrayscaleFilter();
        case SEPIA:
            return new GPUImageSepiaFilter();
        case SHARPEN:
            GPUImageSharpenFilter sharpness = new GPUImageSharpenFilter();
            sharpness.setSharpness(2.0f);
            return sharpness;
        case SOBEL_EDGE_DETECTION:
            return new GPUImageSobelEdgeDetection();
        case THREE_X_THREE_CONVOLUTION:
            GPUImage3x3ConvolutionFilter convolution = new GPUImage3x3ConvolutionFilter();
            convolution.setConvolutionKernel(new float[] {
                    -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                    -2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f,
                    -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
            });
            return convolution;
        case EMBOSS:
            return new GPUImageEmbossFilter();
        case POSTERIZE:
            return new GPUImagePosterizeFilter();
        case FILTER_GROUP:
            List<GPUImageFilter> filters = new LinkedList<GPUImageFilter>();
            filters.add(new GPUImageContrastFilter());
            filters.add(new GPUImageDirectionalSobelEdgeDetectionFilter());
            filters.add(new GPUImageGrayscaleFilter());
            return new GPUImageFilterGroup(filters);
        case SATURATION:
            return new GPUImageSaturationFilter(1.0f);
        case EXPOSURE:
            return new GPUImageExposureFilter(0.0f);
        case HIGHLIGHT_SHADOW:
            return new GPUImageHighlightShadowFilter(0.0f, 1.0f);
        case MONOCHROME:
            return new GPUImageMonochromeFilter(1.0f, new float[]{0.6f, 0.45f, 0.3f, 1.0f});
        case OPACITY:
            return new GPUImageOpacityFilter(1.0f);
        case RGB:
            return new GPUImageRGBFilter(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        case WHITE_BALANCE:
            return new GPUImageWhiteBalanceFilter(5000.0f, 0.0f);
        case VIGNETTE:
            PointF centerPoint = new PointF();
            centerPoint.x = 0.5f;
            centerPoint.y = 0.5f;
            return new GPUImageVignetteFilter(centerPoint, new float[] {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, 0.3f, 0.75f);
        case TONE_CURVE:
            GPUImageToneCurveFilter toneCurveFilter = new GPUImageToneCurveFilter();
            toneCurveFilter.setFromCurveFileInputStream(
                    context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tone_cuver_sample));
            return toneCurveFilter;
        case BLEND_DIFFERENCE:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageDifferenceBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_SOURCE_OVER:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageSourceOverBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_COLOR_BURN:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageColorBurnBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_COLOR_DODGE:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageColorDodgeBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_DARKEN:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageDarkenBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_DISSOLVE:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageDissolveBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_EXCLUSION:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageExclusionBlendFilter.class);


        case BLEND_HARD_LIGHT:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageHardLightBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_LIGHTEN:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageLightenBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_ADD:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageAddBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_DIVIDE:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageDivideBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_MULTIPLY:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_OVERLAY:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_SCREEN:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageScreenBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_ALPHA:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_COLOR:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageColorBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_HUE:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageHueBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_SATURATION:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageSaturationBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_LUMINOSITY:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageLuminosityBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_LINEAR_BURN:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageLinearBurnBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_SOFT_LIGHT:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageSoftLightBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_SUBTRACT:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageSubtractBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_CHROMA_KEY:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter.class);
        case BLEND_NORMAL:
            return createBlendFilter(context, GPUImageNormalBlendFilter.class);

        case LOOKUP_AMATORKA:
            GPUImageLookupFilter amatorka = new GPUImageLookupFilter();
            amatorka.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.lookup_amatorka));
            return amatorka;
        case GAUSSIAN_BLUR:
            return new GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter();
        case CROSSHATCH:
            return new GPUImageCrosshatchFilter();

        case BOX_BLUR:
            return new GPUImageBoxBlurFilter();
        case CGA_COLORSPACE:
            return new GPUImageCGAColorspaceFilter();
        case DILATION:
            return new GPUImageDilationFilter();
        case KUWAHARA:
            return new GPUImageKuwaharaFilter();
        case RGB_DILATION:
            return new GPUImageRGBDilationFilter();
        case SKETCH:
            return new GPUImageSketchFilter();
        case TOON:
            return new GPUImageToonFilter();
        case SMOOTH_TOON:
            return new GPUImageSmoothToonFilter();

        case BULGE_DISTORTION:
            return new GPUImageBulgeDistortionFilter();
        case GLASS_SPHERE:
            return new GPUImageGlassSphereFilter();
        case HAZE:
            return new GPUImageHazeFilter();
        case LAPLACIAN:
            return new GPUImageLaplacianFilter();
        case NON_MAXIMUM_SUPPRESSION:
            return new GPUImageNonMaximumSuppressionFilter();
        case SPHERE_REFRACTION:
            return new GPUImageSphereRefractionFilter();
        case SWIRL:
            return new GPUImageSwirlFilter();
        case WEAK_PIXEL_INCLUSION:
            return new GPUImageWeakPixelInclusionFilter();
        case FALSE_COLOR:
            return new GPUImageFalseColorFilter();
        case COLOR_BALANCE:
            return new GPUImageColorBalanceFilter();
        case LEVELS_FILTER_MIN:
            GPUImageLevelsFilter levelsFilter = new GPUImageLevelsFilter();
            levelsFilter.setMin(0.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f);
            return levelsFilter;

        case BILATERAL_BLUR:
            return new GPUImageBilateralFilter();

        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("No filter of that type!");
    }

}

private static GPUImageFilter createBlendFilter(Context context, Class<? extends GPUImageTwoInputFilter> filterClass) {
    try {
        GPUImageTwoInputFilter filter = filterClass.newInstance();
        filter.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        return filter;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public interface OnGpuImageFilterChosenListener {
    void onGpuImageFilterChosenListener(GPUImageFilter filter);
}

private enum FilterType {
    CONTRAST, GRAYSCALE, SHARPEN, SEPIA, SOBEL_EDGE_DETECTION, THREE_X_THREE_CONVOLUTION, FILTER_GROUP, EMBOSS, POSTERIZE, GAMMA, BRIGHTNESS, INVERT, HUE, PIXELATION,
    SATURATION, EXPOSURE, HIGHLIGHT_SHADOW, MONOCHROME, OPACITY, RGB, WHITE_BALANCE, VIGNETTE, TONE_CURVE, BLEND_COLOR_BURN, BLEND_COLOR_DODGE, BLEND_DARKEN, BLEND_DIFFERENCE,
    BLEND_DISSOLVE, BLEND_EXCLUSION, BLEND_SOURCE_OVER, BLEND_HARD_LIGHT, BLEND_LIGHTEN, BLEND_ADD, BLEND_DIVIDE, BLEND_MULTIPLY, BLEND_OVERLAY, BLEND_SCREEN, BLEND_ALPHA,
    BLEND_COLOR, BLEND_HUE, BLEND_SATURATION, BLEND_LUMINOSITY, BLEND_LINEAR_BURN, BLEND_SOFT_LIGHT, BLEND_SUBTRACT, BLEND_CHROMA_KEY, BLEND_NORMAL, LOOKUP_AMATORKA,
    GAUSSIAN_BLUR, CROSSHATCH, BOX_BLUR, CGA_COLORSPACE, DILATION, KUWAHARA, RGB_DILATION, SKETCH, TOON, SMOOTH_TOON, BULGE_DISTORTION, GLASS_SPHERE, HAZE, LAPLACIAN, NON_MAXIMUM_SUPPRESSION,
    SPHERE_REFRACTION, SWIRL, WEAK_PIXEL_INCLUSION, FALSE_COLOR, COLOR_BALANCE, LEVELS_FILTER_MIN, BILATERAL_BLUR
}

private static class FilterList {
    public List<String> names = new LinkedList<String>();
    public List<FilterType> filters = new LinkedList<FilterType>();

    public void addFilter(final String name, final FilterType filter) {
        names.add(name);
        filters.add(filter);
    }
}

public static class FilterAdjuster {
    private final Adjuster<? extends GPUImageFilter> adjuster;

    public FilterAdjuster(final GPUImageFilter filter) {
        if (filter instanceof GPUImageSharpenFilter) {
            adjuster = new SharpnessAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageSepiaFilter) {
            adjuster = new SepiaAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageContrastFilter) {
            adjuster = new ContrastAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageGammaFilter) {
            adjuster = new GammaAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageBrightnessFilter) {
            adjuster = new BrightnessAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageSobelEdgeDetection) {
            adjuster = new SobelAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageEmbossFilter) {
            adjuster = new EmbossAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImage3x3TextureSamplingFilter) {
            adjuster = new GPU3x3TextureAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageHueFilter) {
            adjuster = new HueAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImagePosterizeFilter) {
            adjuster = new PosterizeAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImagePixelationFilter) {
            adjuster = new PixelationAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageSaturationFilter) {
            adjuster = new SaturationAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageExposureFilter) {
            adjuster = new ExposureAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageHighlightShadowFilter) {
            adjuster = new HighlightShadowAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageMonochromeFilter) {
            adjuster = new MonochromeAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageOpacityFilter) {
            adjuster = new OpacityAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageRGBFilter) {
            adjuster = new RGBAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageWhiteBalanceFilter) {
            adjuster = new WhiteBalanceAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageVignetteFilter) {
            adjuster = new VignetteAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageDissolveBlendFilter) {
            adjuster = new DissolveBlendAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter) {
            adjuster = new GaussianBlurAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageCrosshatchFilter) {
            adjuster = new CrosshatchBlurAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageBulgeDistortionFilter) {
            adjuster = new BulgeDistortionAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageGlassSphereFilter) {
            adjuster = new GlassSphereAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageHazeFilter) {
            adjuster = new HazeAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageSphereRefractionFilter) {
            adjuster = new SphereRefractionAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageSwirlFilter) {
            adjuster = new SwirlAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageColorBalanceFilter) {
            adjuster = new ColorBalanceAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageLevelsFilter) {
            adjuster = new LevelsMinMidAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else if (filter instanceof GPUImageBilateralFilter) {
            adjuster = new BilateralAdjuster().filter(filter);
        }
        else {

            adjuster = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean canAdjust() {
        return adjuster != null;
    }

    public void adjust(final int percentage) {
        if (adjuster != null) {
            adjuster.adjust(percentage);
        }
    }

    private abstract class Adjuster<T extends GPUImageFilter> {
        private T filter;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Adjuster<T> filter(final GPUImageFilter filter) {
            this.filter = (T) filter;
            return this;
        }

        public T getFilter() {
            return filter;
        }

        public abstract void adjust(int percentage);

        protected float range(final int percentage, final float start, final float end) {
            return (end - start) * percentage / 100.0f + start;
        }

        protected int range(final int percentage, final int start, final int end) {
            return (end - start) * percentage / 100 + start;
        }
    }

    private class SharpnessAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageSharpenFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setSharpness(range(percentage, -4.0f, 4.0f));
        }
    }

    private class PixelationAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImagePixelationFilter> {
      @Override
      public void adjust(final int percentage) {
          getFilter().setPixel(range(percentage, 1.0f, 100.0f));
      }
    }

    private class HueAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageHueFilter> {
      @Override
      public void adjust(final int percentage) {
        getFilter().setHue(range(percentage, 0.0f, 360.0f));
      }
    }

    private class ContrastAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageContrastFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setContrast(range(percentage, 0.0f, 2.0f));
        }
    }

    private class GammaAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageGammaFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setGamma(range(percentage, 0.0f, 3.0f));
        }
    }

    private class BrightnessAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageBrightnessFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setBrightness(range(percentage, -1.0f, 1.0f));
        }
    }

    private class SepiaAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageSepiaFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setIntensity(range(percentage, 0.0f, 2.0f));
        }
    }

    private class SobelAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageSobelEdgeDetection> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setLineSize(range(percentage, 0.0f, 5.0f));
        }
    }

    private class EmbossAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageEmbossFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setIntensity(range(percentage, 0.0f, 4.0f));
        }
    }

    private class PosterizeAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImagePosterizeFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            // In theorie to 256, but only first 50 are interesting
            getFilter().setColorLevels(range(percentage, 1, 50));
        }
    }

    private class GPU3x3TextureAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImage3x3TextureSamplingFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setLineSize(range(percentage, 0.0f, 5.0f));
        }
    }

    private class SaturationAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageSaturationFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setSaturation(range(percentage, 0.0f, 2.0f));
        }
    }

    private class ExposureAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageExposureFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setExposure(range(percentage, -10.0f, 10.0f));
        }
    }   

    private class HighlightShadowAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageHighlightShadowFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setShadows(range(percentage, 0.0f, 1.0f));
            getFilter().setHighlights(range(percentage, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        }
    }

    private class MonochromeAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageMonochromeFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setIntensity(range(percentage, 0.0f, 1.0f));
            //getFilter().setColor(new float[]{0.6f, 0.45f, 0.3f, 1.0f});
        }
    }

    private class OpacityAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageOpacityFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setOpacity(range(percentage, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        }
    }   

    private class RGBAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageRGBFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setRed(range(percentage, 0.0f, 1.0f));
            //getFilter().setGreen(range(percentage, 0.0f, 1.0f));
            //getFilter().setBlue(range(percentage, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        }
    }   

    private class WhiteBalanceAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageWhiteBalanceFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setTemperature(range(percentage, 2000.0f, 8000.0f));
            //getFilter().setTint(range(percentage, -100.0f, 100.0f));
        }
    }

    private class VignetteAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageVignetteFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setVignetteStart(range(percentage, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        }
    }

    private class DissolveBlendAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageDissolveBlendFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setMix(range(percentage, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        }
    }

    private class GaussianBlurAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setBlurSize(range(percentage, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        }
    }

    private class CrosshatchBlurAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageCrosshatchFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setCrossHatchSpacing(range(percentage, 0.0f, 0.06f));
            getFilter().setLineWidth(range(percentage, 0.0f, 0.006f));
        }
    }

    private class BulgeDistortionAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageBulgeDistortionFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setRadius(range(percentage, 0.0f, 1.0f));
            getFilter().setScale(range(percentage, -1.0f, 1.0f));
        }
    }

    private class GlassSphereAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageGlassSphereFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setRadius(range(percentage, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        }
    }

    private class HazeAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageHazeFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setDistance(range(percentage, -0.3f, 0.3f));
            getFilter().setSlope(range(percentage, -0.3f, 0.3f));
        }
    }
```